# Merge three arrays and order this new array by position field

Tags: php

I have 3 arrays and I am merging them with the `array_merge` function. This is giving correct results; one array is appending with next array.

But I want to display my array based on the `position` field.

```
$this->array1 = $this->function1();
$this->array2 = $this->function2();
$this->array3 = this->function3();
$this->result= array_merge( $this->array1,$this->array2,this->array3);
```

I'm getting the following result from above array merge:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 1
            [id_product] => 1904
            [position] => 1
            [active] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 6
            [id_product] => 1386
            [position] => 3
            [active] => 1

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 5
            [id_product] => 2008
            [position] => 2
        [active] => 1

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 8
            [id_product] => 0
            [id_category] => 0
            [position] => 99
            [active] => 1
        )

)
```

But I want the array to be display based on the `postion` field like:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 1
            [id_product] => 1904
            [position] => 1
            [active] => 1

        )



    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 5
            [id_product] => 2008
            [position] => 2
            [active] => 1

        )

  [1] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 6
            [id_product] => 1386
            [position] => 3
            [active] => 1

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_custom] => 8
            [id_product] => 0
            [id_category] => 0
            [position] => 99
            [set_devices] => 
            [active] => 1
        )

)
```

Any idea how to display the array based on the `position` field?

Comment: You want to update your array order by `id_custom` field?

Comment: have a look at usort() function
http://php.net/usort

Comment: @BinaryBrackets i want update my array order by position field,because in each  select query i am showing order by ASC position,but after merge the array position is not coming proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort an array based on a field you need to use the `usort` function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

This allows you to write a custom compare function so that, given two elements on the array, you tell which one should come first.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
function comparePosition($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['position'] == $b['position']) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a['position'] < $b['position']) {
        return -1;
    }    
    return 1;
}

usort($this->array1, 'comparePosition');
```

Comment: ,its working fine!!! thanks